# Apple Watch stopped Monday update of my move goal

Tags: apple-watch

Sometime a few months ago, my Apple Watch stopped offering an updated move goal on Monday mornings. My wife’s watch has been in this state for a couple years. Does anybody know how to get it back?

I have a suspicion that it might be related to my experimenting with sleep tracking with the watch since it stopped working about the same time I tried a suggestion from daring fireball that I can no longer find that required doing something with sleep tracking to get a charging notification(?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record, with the update in WatchOS last month, the problem resolved itself, so whatever bug was impacting me was fixed in that release.